Looking for way to get a list of all class / struct from a C++ Windows program
I'm debugging some suspected memory leak issue, and I see in Windbg heap stats a large list of allocations of specific size.
Traditionally - to find the source of the allocation I have used Gflags, reproduce the issue and looked at the stacks information.
But I'm wondering - the size of class / struct is known at compile time, isn't there a way to get the list of classes + their size from the symbols somehow ?
Even just the list of class names - these I can feed to windbg to calculate their size:
?? sizeof(CLASS_NAME)
Anyone know of such way ?
I'm not interested in 3rd party tools / profilers, just this specific task - as I'm usually given only a process dump after the issue had happened - so its too late to use this tools

Better suited for reverseengineering.se, but if the code was compiled with RTTI you can find the vtables' addresses and from there see where they are loaded into fresh memory allocations. Either way, if you know the compiler used that would help (look at the runtime dll it requires to get a hint)

Rough idea - compile with debug information, then dump it with something like pdbdump and filter/massage that dump to get information you need with jq.

Actually scratch that. windbg already can do what you need. dt command lists symbols, dt -s  can filter them by size.

Does this answer your question? Finding memory leaks in a C++ application with Visual Studio

Debug Diag with leak tracing can get you started.

@BoP - Unfortunately no - I usually have in hand only a process dump after the issue had happened

@AndreyTurkin Thanks! 'dt -s SIZE MODULE!*' does the trick assuming we know what module is used

@Andrey Turkin comment gave me a useful way,
dt -s SIZE MODULE!*
Does the trick.
If anyone knows of a quick global way for all modules - also useful (I feel there is a way with windbg scripting, but I'm not a fan of that method)
Update:
dt -s SIZE -n *!*

Seems to work

What about *!* ? I think that should work also

Tried it, didn't worked. Stuff like A*!* works for all modules that start with A. but the ! does not work
